# Google WIFI is giving all devices on the network the same public ip addres

Tags: networking, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I wanted to try and setup a minecraft server form me and friends hosted on my local pc. One of my friends that i had i a discord call did the same thing. Everything went simular for us untill one point. When i was to join his Minecraft server he serched up his public ip addres with googles Whats my IP. I enterd the ip as a server and got in. Then it was his turn to join my server. I did the same thing and googled whats my IP, gave it to him and then he tried to join, it didn't work. I could join the server with localhost but he could not join with my public ip addres.

After more research i found that all devices connected to this network had the same Public IP. I am not so in to network and stuff so i hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What probably happens is that on his network "port forwarding" is enabled, but not in yours.

To explain it simply, when you connect to a (minecraft) server, you specify the IP and the port. When you send a packet to his IP, the packet goes to his router and his router "knows" that a packet that comes from port XXX should be redirected on port YYY on local IP "your_friend_local_ip". this is port forwarding

On your network, if port forwarding is not enabled, your friend connects on your router on port XXX but your router doesn't know where to redirect this packets and drops it.

You want to enable "port forwarding" on your router with the following configuration :

- IP (private) address : your local IP address (it should look like 192.168.x.x)
- External/public port : the port you want your friend to (1234 for example)
- Internal/private port : the port your minecraft server is running on (25565 by default)
- Traffic type : all (both TCP and UDP)

That way when your friend connects to your_public_ip on port 1234, it will be redirected to 192.168.x.x (your machine) on port 25565

Comment: Sorry that I am a bit late, solved it myself and forgot about this post but thanks anyways!